# ExpressionEngine with Publisher and NavEE

Tags: ee5, navee, publisher, ee4-upgrade

Recently, I upgraded EE v2.9 website to EE v5.3.2 which is multi-language website managed with [Publisher](https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher). I am facing problem after upgrade. None of custom fields like Textarea, RTE etc populating content.

Another problem is that [NavEE](https://www.theout.fit/navee) is being used to managed navigation and I can't find EE5 ported version for add-on [Publisher NavEE Support](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher-navee-support)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with fields not populating will be hard to diagnose without you providing more information about how the fields were defined and how you are trying to access them / include in templates.

As for the Publisher / NavEE support - wasn't too hard to find [this](https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher-navee-support) on the BoldMinded site, which is indicated as working with EE4/5.

If this doesn't work with EE5, I'd get in touch with BoldMinded and see what they suggest.

Comment: Thanks @JCOGS - Yes, I found that add-on "Publisher - NavEE Support" but unfortunately doesn't seem working with EE5. So decided to go with Publisher + Structure.